# How to use multiple IF conditions with excel formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am working on a excel matching records, was trying to use IF formula, but I am not sure what I've done wrong on the formula

The criteria:
if E2 or C2 = "Record Match", and B3 = B4, **B3+B4** or if B3 = B4 = B5 then add **B3+B4+B5**
else, if B3 = B4, **B3+B4** or if B3 = B4 = B5, **B3+B4+B5**

my formula:
`=IF(OR(C2="Record Match",E2="Record Match"),IF(B3=B4,A3+A4),IF(COUNTIF(B3:B5,B5)=3,A3+A4+A5), IF(B3=B4,A3+A4),IF(COUNTIF(B3:B5,B5)=3,A3+A4+A5))`

[image]

Comment: Please edit your formula to format it properly by using backticks ( ` ) `like this`. Also, do not base your code around images.

Comment: `-30 + -10 = -45` I'm sorry, what? You will have to simplify it further. Are you asking to `SUM()` all rows if the name is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

[image]

Using Tables makes this much easier for you to reference.
Paste into C2:

```
=SUMIF([Symbol];[@Symbol];[Num])
```

However, if you insist on not using Tables, you have to lock the references using `$`:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$10;$B2;$A$2:$A$10)
```